# Extreme points and convex hull

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polyhedra, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

**Definition 1:** The **convex hull** of a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the smallest convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contains $S$. I denote it by the symbol $\mbox{Conv}(S)$. If $S$ is a finite set, i.e. $S=\{g_1,\dots, g_k\}$ I will write $\mbox{Conv}(g_1,\dots, g_k)$.

---

**Definition 2:** Let $C$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x\in C$. I say that $x$ is an **extreme point** of $C$ if $x$ cannot be expressed as a strict convex combination of two distinct points $a,b$ of $C$ with $a\ne x$ and $b\ne x$.

---

**Proposition**: if $g_1,\dots, g_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are points and $x$ is **not** an extreme point of $$C := \mbox{Conv}(g_1,\dots,g_k,x)$$ then $$\mbox{Conv} (g_1, \dots, g_k, x) = \mbox{Conv} (g_1, \dots, g_k)$$

---

I *suspect* that this proposition is true and I'm trying to prove it. The inclusion $\supseteq$ is trivial. I have to prove the other inclusion, i.e. $\subseteq$. It sufficies to prove that $x\in Conv(g_1,\dots, g_k)$. By the hypothesis we have that there exist two different points $a,b\in C$, with $a\ne x$ and $b\ne x$, and a scalar $0<\theta<1$ such that $x=\theta a+(1-\theta)b$. Since $a, b\in C$, we have that there exist

$$\mu_1,\dots, \mu_k,\mu_{k+1},\eta_1,\dots,\eta_k,\eta_{k+1}\in\mathbb{R}_0^+$$

such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\mu_i=1$, $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\eta_i=1$ and $a=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\mu_ig_i$, $b=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\eta_ig_i$. Then I have

$$x=\sum_{i=1}^k\theta\mu_i g_i+\sum_{i=1}^k(1-\theta)\eta_ig_i+\theta\mu_{k+1}x+(1-\theta)\eta_{k+1}x$$

i.e.,

$$(1-\theta\mu_{k+1}-(1-\theta)\eta_{k+1})x=\sum_{i=1}^k\theta\mu_i g_i+\sum_{i=1}^k(1-\theta)\eta_ig_i$$

Now if I show that $1-\theta\mu_{k+1}-(1-\theta)\eta_{k+1}\ne 0$ I would finish the proof. But I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: There must be a minus sign in front of $(1-\theta)\eta_{k+1}$. Guess, this is a typo. Now, if the expression is zero, then $\theta \mu_{k+1} + (1-\theta)\eta_{k+1} = 1$. The left hand side is a convex combination of $\mu_{k+1}$ and $\eta_{k+1}$, so it's "between" these two numbers. If this is one, what will that imply?

Comment: That's right, It's a typing error. I'm trying to use your hint, maybe I can use the fact that the 1 is an extreme point of the range $[0,1]$?

Comment: Again: the equality tells you that $1$ is between $\mu$ and $\eta$. But since both of these numbers are in $[0,1]$, both of them are equal to one. But this implies that all the other $\mu$'s and $\eta$'s must be zero. Hence, in particular, $a=\sum_{i=1}^k\mu_ig_i + \mu_{k+1}x = x$, which contradicts your assumption that $a\neq x$.

Comment: Ok everything now it's clear, thank you very much! @amsmath

Comment: You're welcome. :-)